# Why does my opengl scene have depth buffer problems?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am reading a heightmap from a file, and rendering it using triangle strips.

The heightmap:

[image]

It works well, this is how it looks :

[image]

It looks alright, but only from this direction. If I turn the camera a bit, this starts happening :

[image]

It seems as if my depth buffer is corrupt. I have it enabled, and it works well with other geometry.

Did anybody have a problem like this before? I don't even know what to search for. Thanks!

Edit :

My projection matrix setup :

1.2062851 0.0 0.0 0.0

0.0 2.1445069 0.0 0.0

0.0 0.0 -1.0 -1.0

0.0 0.0 -0.2 0.0

```
_fieldOfView(50.0f),
_nearPlane(0.1f),
_farPlane(10000.0f),
_viewportAspectRatio(16.0f/9.0f)
```

Comment: Could you show your projection matrix set up, and also the heightmap file contents? :)

Comment: It might also help to turn on wireframe mode to visually inspect the artifacts. `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replying. I updated the question. Activating wireframe was the first I did, and it looks fine there - http://i.snag.gy/fKpx1.jpg

Comment: Could be depth fighting. You have a very large ratio of far to near plane. Try increasing the near plane value, or decreasing the far plane value.

Comment: Interesting, say, have you tried changing far plane to something smaller like 10.0f or 100.0f?

Comment: It happens even when I set far plane to 100. I read about depth fighting also, but this doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Did you request some depth buffer bits when you created your GL context?  You may not get any from the OS unless you ask for them.  Did you enable depth testing?

Comment: Hey, I found the solution. I had to re-enable depth testing for every frame, and not once on renderer creation. It works well now, thanks for all your help! Is there any way to accept comments? :)
End product : http://i.snag.gy/CsdJ2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your helpful comments. I found the issue, and hope that others who have this problem will find the solution useful. I had to re-enable depth buffering before each frame (glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)), instead of once at renderer creation. I was under the impression that this was a global state, and thus wouldn't need to be reset everytime I render.

The end product looks like this, with no depth buffer problems :

[image]

Anyhow, hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Actually `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` is a global state.

Comment: You might be updating the state of `GL_DEPTH_TEST` somewhere in your program, make sure you search for all instances of `GL_DEPTH_TEST` to sanitize how you are handling it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, will check for that.